# Magento 2.3.2 Authorize.net Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Just setup a fresh install of Magento2.3.2 and enabled Authorize.net 
now when I try to do a transaction I just get a spinner on the checkout page and in the console I get an error that says the below and not sure what to do. Also I notice a field in the Authorize.net admin panel labeled public Key but idk where to get that. I have the API ID, Transaction key and Signature Key. What is the Public Key and where do I get it? Maybe because I have that field blank thats why I get this error?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at b (AcceptCore.js:1)
at Object.a.dispatchData.a.dispatchData (AcceptCore.js:1)
at UiClass._createTokens (acceptjs-client.js:59)
at UiClass.<anonymous> (acceptjs-client.js:45)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
at Object.deferred.<computed> [as resolve] (jquery.js:3461)
at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (acceptjs-factory.js:29)
at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5226)
at HTMLBodyElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4878)
at v (AcceptCore.js:1)
at w (AcceptCore.js:1)
at AcceptCore.js:1
at AcceptCore.js:1
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common reasons of this issue is the Public Client Key not being specified or wrong key in the Authorize.Net configuration in the Magento Admin.

> Solution:

Under `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods`, in the `Authorize.net` section, check if the value is specified in the Public Client Key field. If it is empty, enter the key value from your Authorize.Net merchant account.

For the changes to be applied, clean the cache by running `bin/magento cache:clean`.

Reference: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360030844171-Checkout-is-stuck-when-Authorize-net-payment-method-is-used

Answer (score 1):

I don't even have a  field for a Public Client Key. I see it defined in system XML but I don't see it in the admin section of authorize.net

Comment: likely that the Public Client Key is just listed as 'Key' in Auth.net - for my sandbox acct, it was 'Simon' - updating that in the Auth.net configuration fixed the OP's AcceptCore.js error for me.